# Gmail image problem - Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('<URL>') does not

Tags: html, dom, gmail, postmessage

I run a website where people frequently copy and paste the output from my website and email it to their clients. The website outputs flight details which includes some images such as below:

[image]

when a user copies the content from my website, pastes it into outlook/mail everything is fine and the images display correctly,

[image]

however if the recipient of the email uses gmail the images display as a broken link

[image]

if I inspect the image element in Gmail then the image src = `https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/ILKyipOTRb8QYVwkcZjePBkX69veJwqeS5fACyVhX2QnAswpuJKXodiMxxv0hRDXoiyxH7W0dsGx4PO9YHpCC8QV=s0-d-e1-ft#https://pnrconverter.com/images/airlines/nz.svg"`

where `https://pnrconverter.com/images/airlines/nz.svg` is the url  where the image is stored.

In the console I get the following error messages

`Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://hangouts.google.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://mail.google.com').`

and then

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()`

Most of the other solutions on stack over flow refer to iframes, however there are no iframes used in my site,

has anyone got any sugegstions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else comes across this problem, the answer is simply that gmail doesn't support svg images. They need to be PNG or JPG!